# https server how to create a list of trusted certificates, Client always get unknown CA

Tags: c++, linux, server, openssl, certificate

My system is Linux.

I try to create a tlsv1.2 https server with Openssl which need check client's certificate, but when Client tries to hands shake with Server, after Client sends Certificate to Server, Server will reply Unknown CA.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2lL8.png)

I can confirm that it is the problem of the certificate, because I will SSL_CTX_set_verify(IEctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, NULL) After the comment is removed, the handshake can be completed.

Is it because the server does not trust this certificate?

Does the server set the trust certificate through SSL_CTX_set_client_CA_list()?

```
    init_openssl_library();
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    // build the SSL objects...
    const SSL_METHOD* method = TLS_server_method();
    SSLeay_add_ssl_algorithms();
    if (!(NULL != method)) fprintf(stderr, "SSL Method Error\n");

    IEctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
    if (!(IEctx != NULL)) fprintf(stderr, "CXT New Error\n");
    SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(IEctx, "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-CCM8");
    SSL_CTX_set_verify(IEctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, NULL);

    SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(IEctx,"sat-root.crt",NULL);
    STACK_OF(X509_NAME)  *list;
    list = SSL_load_client_CA_file("Root.pem");
        
    if (list == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to load client CA file from \"Root.pem\"\n");
        //return -1;
    }
    SSL_CTX_set_client_CA_list(IEctx, SSL_load_client_CA_file("Root.pem"));
    SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(IEctx, "sat-root.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);//root CA
    SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file(IEctx, "sat-cli_mca-mica-dev_55937-13-1_56000020.pem");//Chain CA
    if (SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(IEctx, "sat-key_dev_55937-13-1_56000020.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0) {//Private Key
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout);
        return 1;
    }
    if (!SSL_CTX_check_private_key(IEctx)) {//Check Private key
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout);
        return 1;
    }
    if (!IEctx) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    }
    IEssl = SSL_new(IEctx);
    SSL_set_fd(IEssl, listener);
    FD_SET(listener, &master);
    if (select(fdmax + 1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, &tv) == -1) {
        perror("select");
        return 4;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= fdmax; i++) {
        if (FD_ISSET(i, &read_fds)) { // 我們找到一個！！
            DC_DEBUG_NL("we find one");
            if (i == listener) {
                DC_DEBUG_NL("i == listener");
                // handle new connections
                addrlen = sizeof remoteaddr;
                newfd = accept(listener, (struct sockaddr *)&remoteaddr, &addrlen);

                if (newfd == -1) {
                    perror("accept");
                } else {
                    DC_DEBUG_NL("add new fd");
                    SSL_set_fd(IEssl, newfd);  //新增到 master set
                    if (newfd > fdmax) {     //持續追蹤最大的 fd
                        fdmax = newfd;
                    }
                    int r = SSL_accept(IEssl);
                    if (r == 1){
                        DC_DEBUG_NL("scuess to accept");
                    }
                    nbytes = SSL_read(IEssl, IEEEBuf, sizeof(IEEEBuf) - 1);
                    DC_DEBUG_NL("IEEEBuf[nbytes]=%s", IEEEBuf);
                    string webpage = "/ntfy/0";
                    string RequestBody = "";
                    string SendstrPacket = "";
                    char chRequest[500];
                    SendstrPacket = https.TransToPacketFormat(P_IE2030, RequestBody, webpage, "", H_Create);
                    StrToChar(chRequest, SendstrPacket);
                    int result = SSL_write(IEssl, chRequest, strlen(chRequest));
                    if(result != -1){
                        DC_DEBUG_NL("scuess to write");
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: Yes, it is because the server doesn't trust the client's certificate. Solutions: (1) import the client certificate into the server's truststore, or (2) have the client certificates signed by a trusted CA. In the long run you will find (2) far simpler.

Comment: the certificate is signed by a official CA, I must trust it, I suspect that I have not included this CA in the trust list, How to build a trusted CA list, is SSL_CTX_set_client_CA_list(list)?  The "list" is .pem?

Comment: `SSL_CTX_set_client_CA_list` only sets the names of allowed CAs sent to the client when requesting a client cert.  It does not affect which CAs are trusted by the server.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/25156180/1216776