# Getting "Problem with the SSL CA cert" error while using libcurl

Tags: c++, linux, curl, libcurl

I've built openssl 1.1.1 with --openssldir=< path to ssl >/ssl (link to /etc/ssl) and curl 7.76.1 with --with-ssl=< path to openssl >.
Compiled the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main()
{
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl)
    {       
        struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: */*");
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://<address>");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "<some data>");
    
        curl_easy_perform(curl);
    
        curl_slist_free_all(headers)
    }
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
```

When I'm running this code I get an error:

```
curl_easy_operation() failed : Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
```

I see in strace, that it's trying to open "/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt"
But in my machines (Ubuntu 12 and Ubuntu 14) there is no folder "/etc/pki".
Why does curl use "/etc/pki" instead of "/etc/ssl"? How can I force it do use "/etc/ssl"?
I tried to build curl with --without-nss, but it didn't work.

EDIT:
My solution was adding this code:

```
ifstream caBundleFile("/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt");
if (caBundleFile.good()) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt");
    caBundleFile.close();
} else {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAPATH, "/etc/ssl/certs");
}
```

There are two popular formats of storing root certificates. First one is for RHEL/Centos like, and second is for Ubuntu like distros.

Comment: Probably you didn't tell it the path to the CA certs and it is using a default path.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/4138139/1216776

Comment: I am facing the same issue. My application is running on windows. Were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: @Captain_Levi, I solved it on Linux by adding options, please see my last edit.